# SWIFTUI: Why adding @State to property doesn't update data model

Tags: swift, swiftui, observedobject

having a problem with updating data in ObservedObject
here's the data MRE:

```
struct Property: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String = ""
    var meters : [Meter] = [Meter(name: "electricity"), Meter(name: "water")]
}
struct Meter: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String = ""
}

class PropertyData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var properties: [Property]
    
    
    func save() {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(properties) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "PropertyData")
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        if let properties = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "PropertyData") {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let decoded = try? decoder.decode([Property].self, from: properties) {
                self.properties = decoded
                return
            }
        }
        self.properties = [
            Property(name: "Saks /1", meters: [Meter(name: "electricity")]),
            Property(name: "Saks /2", meters: [Meter(name: "electricity"), Meter(name: "water")]),
        ]
    }
}


import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data = PropertyData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(data.properties, id:\.self) {property in
                    NavigationLink(destination: NavigationLinkView(data: data, property: property)) {
                        Text(property.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NavigationLinkView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data : PropertyData
    var property:Property
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            MetersView(data: data, property: property)
                .tabItem{
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "scroll")
                        Text("Utitity")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct MetersView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: PropertyData
    @State private var metersPage = 0
    @State var property : Property
    @State private var addMeters = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Picker("Meters", selection: $metersPage) {
                    ForEach (0 ..< property.meters.count, id:\.self) {index in
                        Text(property.meters[index].name)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                Button{
                    print(property.meters)
                    addMeters.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                }
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
        }.sheet(isPresented: $addMeters){AddMetersView(data: data, property: $property)}
    }
}

struct AddMetersView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data : PropertyData
    @Binding var property : Property
    @State var newMeter: String = ""
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form{
                Section {
                    TextField("Add another meter", text: $newMeter)
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                    Button{
                        if newMeter != "" {
                            property.meters.append(Meter(name: newMeter))
                            data.save()
                            print(property.meters.count)
                        }                    } label: {
                            Text("Add a meter")
                        }
                }
                ForEach(0..<property.meters.count, id:\ .self) {index in
                    Text(property.meters[index].name)
                }
                Section() {
                    Button("That's enough"){
                        print(property.meters)
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot understand, why the meters, that I add on AddMetersView, do update the Meters page, but then just goes away as soon as I go to the ContentView.
Plus, in my app, if I add a property, it does stay, and it persists, but not the Meters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to your previous question. Change `@State var property : Property` to

It is all about the connections. You break them in a few places along the way I made some changes and put comments along the line.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MetersParentView: View {
    //Change to StateObject
    @StateObject var data = PropertyData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach($data.properties, id:\.id) {$property in
                    NavigationLink(destination: NavigationLinkView(data: data, property: $property)) {
                        Text(property.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NavigationLinkView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data : PropertyData
    //Make Binding there is no connection without it
    @Binding var property : Property
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            MetersView(data: data, property: $property)
                .tabItem{
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "scroll")
                        Text("Utitity")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct MetersView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: PropertyData
    @State var selectedMeter: Meter = .init()
    //Change to Binding
    //State is a source of truth, it breaks the connection
    @Binding var property : Property
    @State private var addMeters = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Picker("Meters", selection: $selectedMeter) {
                    //Use object not index
                    ForEach(property.meters, id:\.id) {meter in
                        //Tag adjustment
                        Text(meter.name).tag(meter as Meter)
                    }
                }.onAppear(perform: {
                    selectedMeter = property.meters.first ?? Meter()
                })
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                Button{
                    print(property.meters)
                    addMeters.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                }
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
        }.sheet(isPresented: $addMeters){
            AddMetersView(data: data, property: $property)
            
        }
    }
}

struct AddMetersView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data : PropertyData
    @Binding var property : Property
    @State var newMeter: String = ""
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form{
                Section {
                    TextField("Add another meter", text: $newMeter)
                        .autocapitalization(.none)
                    Button{
                        if newMeter != "" {
                            print(property.meters.count)
                            property.meters.append(Meter(name: newMeter))
                            print(property.meters.count)
                            data.save()
                            print(property.meters.count)
                        }
                        
                    } label: {
                        Text("Add a meter")
                    }
                }
                //Dont use index
                ForEach(property.meters, id:\ .id) {meter in
                    Text(meter.name)
                }
                Section() {
                    Button("That's enough"){
                        print(property.meters)
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct MetersParentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MetersParentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: But in the view, where I added the meter, it saves the data to data model. Shouldn't there be any more problems? Maybe I should just get rid of var property: Property and just pass the data?

Comment: The `Picker` in `MetersView` will updated with the new item if your bindings are correct. it is like a string of two-way connections. `@State` breaks the connection because it is a source of truth. `@Published var properties` should be your only source of truth the rest of the connections should be done with an `@Binding`

Comment: the Picker works. One thing I cannot understand:
there's PropertyData which is the source of truth, I update this source of truth, when  I add a new meter and I save this PropertyData. So why it is not there next time...

Comment: @RomanR Where do you add anything, where do you save anything?

Comment: With the code right now you are not persisting. At no point are you writing back to you JSON. When you call `save` it should in theory save everything to the JSON but that is only if your connections are correct and the `try?` isn't failing. Rightnow you are ignoring failures use `do catch` to see if there are any.

Comment: I added the code, where I save data.even if it is not saved - it should at least work for the period, when app is open, but it is not

Comment: Provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) something to copy and paste and get to see the whole picture. Put it in a new project all in a single file.

Comment: there's a MRE and it doesn't work as it should and the worst thing is that I can't figure out why...

Comment: @RomanR I changed the answer. It is all about keeping the connection

Comment: @loremipsum, wow, that's incredible... I wouldn't think about binding it like that... Thank you a lot, you're breathtaking!!!

Comment: @loremipsum, sorry for bothering you again, I loved, how you make tags as Meter, but how do I make the selection pick the first of Meters? property.meters[0] wouldn't work, and just naming it - would spoil the idea. Is it possible?

Comment: @RomanR No problem, just do it `onAppear` of the `Picker`. I added the code to the `MetersView`. If you want you can upvote my answer. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @loremipsum, I am really sorry, but it seems, that I am totally lost now... cause now, it is adding Meters, but as soon as I want to add data to meter (it is a [MeterData]), i send two bindings to next view Bindging property and Binding meter, but it doesn't save the data... it adds it until the button is pressed

Comment: @RomanR I'm having a hard time following but if you are talking about passing `selectedMeter` to another `View` and changing the variables within`selectedMeter` it would not talk back to anything. `selectedMeter` is an `@State` therefore a source of truth. You haven't showed how you will use it or how it connects. You can ask another question with your new code. Don't forget the Minimal Reproducible Example. Ill be logging out in a bit but somebody else can help or maybe I'll see it later.

Comment: @loremipsum, thanks, I guess I have to read more into it... but you've been so much help

Comment: @loremipsum, once more thank you for your working solution. I got the idea from it and then watched some of the samples from apple developed resources and now I understood the logic, so it is much clearer for me now. Thanks

Comment: @RomanR you are welcome! I’m glad it helped!

Comment: @loremipsum, one more question: if I make 
.onAppear(perform: {selectedMeter = property.meters.first ?? Meter()})
it unselects picker as soon as the view gets redrawn, though the underlying view stays correct, how to overcome this?

Comment: depending on what is causing it. since the default is `Meter()` maybe put a check around it. Something like `if selectedMeter != Meter()`