# How to delete an element in deep nested array

Tags: arrays, parsing, swiftui, nested, save

I have a deep nested arrays JSON file and I would like to delete an object in the last nested array(called series) based on index provided by a swipe button and save the remaining objects in FileManager. For a one level nested Array I can access it, however I can't for the last nested array called series.

Updated: working minimal version for deleting & refresh issue jumping back

```
class Programs: ObservableObject {
  
   @Published var programLists: [ProgramList]
    
    init() {
        self.programLists = [
            ProgramList(id: 1, name: "program 1", workouts: [
                Workout(id: 1, weekDays: "Monday", muscles: [Muscle(id: 1, name: "Back", exercises: [Exercise(id: 1, name: "Seated Row", series: [
                    Serie(id: 1, name: "S1", reps: "6-8", rest: "60s", tempo: "Normal", weight: "70kg"),
                    Serie(id: 2, name: "S2", reps: "6-8", rest: "60s", tempo: "Normal", weight: "70kg"),
                    Serie(id: 3, name: "S3", reps: "6-8", rest: "60s", tempo: "Normal", weight: "70kg")
                ])])])])
        ]
    }
}

struct ProgramList: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var workouts: [Workout]
}

struct Workout: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable {
    var id: Int
    var weekDays: String
    var muscles: [Muscle]
}

struct Muscle: Identifiable, Codable,Equatable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var exercises: [Exercise]
}

struct Exercise: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var series: [Serie]
}

struct Serie : Identifiable, Codable, Equatable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var reps: String
    var rest: String
    var tempo: String
    var weight: String
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var data: Programs = Programs()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
                ForEach($data.programLists) { $item in
                    VStack{
                        Text("\(item.name)")
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: WeekDay(workouts: $item.workouts)){
                          
                            HStack (spacing:8){
                                Text("Start")
                                Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle")
                                    .imageScale(.large)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        // Need to be added to avoid to jump back to the first NavigationLink after the refresh of the last view
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        .environmentObject(data)
    }
}

struct WeekDay: View {
    
    @Binding var workouts: [Workout]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ForEach($workouts) {$item in
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: ExerciseList(muscles: $item.muscles)){
                        VStack{
                            Text("\(item.weekDays) Workout")
                            
                            HStack (spacing:8){
                                Text("Level 1: Go to next Level")
                                Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle")
                                    .imageScale(.large)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExerciseList: View {
 
    @Binding var muscles:[Muscle]
 
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach($muscles){ $muscle in
                Section (header:
                            Text("Muscle Group: \(muscle.name)")
                            .font(.title3)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(.orange)
                )
                {
                    ForEach($muscle.exercises){ $exercise in
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailedView(exercise: $exercise)
                        ){
                            VStack{
                                
                                Text("Exercise Name: \(exercise.name)")
                                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold))
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .padding()
                                
                                HStack{
                                    Text("Level 2: Go to next Level")
                                    Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle")
                                        .imageScale(.large)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailedView: View {
 
    @Binding var exercise: Exercise
    
    let label:[String] = ["Serie", "Reps", "Rest", "Tempo", "Weight"]
    
    var body: some View {
       
            VStack {
                VStack{
                    Text("\(exercise.name)")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.orange)
                        .padding(.top, 20)
              
                    HStack {
                        
                        ForEach(0..<label.count, id: \.self) { item in
                            Spacer(minLength: 10)
                            Text(label[item])
                                .font(.body)
                            Spacer(minLength: 5)
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                    
                    ListSerie(exercise: $exercise)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .listStyle(.grouped)
    }
}

struct ListSerie: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var data: Programs
    @Binding var exercise: Exercise
   
    
    var body: some View {
     
        List {
           
            ForEach($exercise.series) { $serie in
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        Text(serie.name)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(serie.reps)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(serie.rest)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(serie.tempo)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(serie.weight)
                           
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 15,  design: .default))
                   
                }
                .swipeActions {
                    Button("Delete") {
                        delete(serie)
        
                    }
                    .tint(.red)
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.grouped)
    
}
    
    func delete(_ serie: Serie) {
        if let index = exercise.series.firstIndex(of: serie){
            exercise.series.remove(at: index)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You issue is ver similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70633073/swiftui-why-adding-state-to-property-doesnt-update-data-model/70633204?noredirect=1#comment124898426_70633204) You are breaking the return connection to the original array when you don't use `@Binding`. `Binding` allows for a two-way connection.

Comment: `Thanks for the link. I added the @Binding to all views  from the @StateObject view (ContentView) and it works. When I delete the serie all views dismiss and I jump back to 2 level up to the Struct Workout. The hierarchy of my views is contentView calls weekdayView (struct Workout) which call excerciselistView (struct Muscle) which call  DetailedView (struct Exercise) through a navigationLink. For ListSerie (struct Serie) it is embedded in the DetailedView. What should I do to keep the current view active and have the refresh only on the ListSerie. Would be helpfull.`

Comment: Impossible to tell you with the code you have provided. Some thing is causing the view to reset. You can search SO for this, people ask all the time or ask a question with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it could be caused by many little things.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I have uploaded all files

Comment: You have to use `@Binding` to make the connection. A `struct` is immutable as your error says. If you use `let` and/or `var` without `@Binding` you can't talk back.   to the source. Look at the question I posted in the first comment. Your code is far from minimal.

Comment: You were correct. My code was far from minimal. I have updated the minimal reproducible example. Everything is working (deleting, saving) based on the link added in the post. Still after deleting the serie, I don't stay on the view, it brings me 2 level up.

Comment: @Iorem ipsum: I found the reason why after deleting the serie, the refresh brought me back 2 level up. It seems with few hierarchy level the NavigationView needs to have attached a  .navigationViewStyle(.stack). Now everything is working as expected. I have just updated a new working version as an exemple for others who may have similar issue. Thanks for your support.